# Bigquery returns Internal error 503: 23 cols X 600,00 rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm querying larger amounts of data and keep getting this error when returning the data.  This started this afternoon.  The query string works find in the bigquery browser tool.  It's only me querying on one machine synchronously.  doubtful that I hit the 20,000 query limite.

Is this a known bug?

Internal Error when querying data.
Error in runSyncQuery:'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "backendError",\n    "message": "Backend Error"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 503,\n  "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n}\n'

setup:
medium instance EC2

1. Query 19 -23 columns of around 600000 rows each.  Total 564 mb
2. max length of query is set to 50,000 (also 100,000 and 500,000)
3. query is extremely slow to return
   Values of the paged results
   current length:  8825
   1 current row:  17650
   2 current row:  26475
   3 current row:  35300
   4 current row:  44125
   5 current row:  52950
   6 Error in runSyncQuery:'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "backendError",\n    "message": "Backend Error"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 503,\n  "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n}\n'

adding additional requested info:
job_183c2c3919dd4d8fac9f2947201978ef 459512762119 current length: 8825 1 current row: 17650 2 current row: 26475 3 Error in runSyncQuery:'{\n "error": {\n "errors": [\n {\n "domain": "global",\n "reason": "backendError",\n "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n ],\n "code": 503,\n "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n}\n'

Comment: Hi this is happening again this morning...is there any way to tke a look at: job id: job_23c773fd534a46db8ab727bcbc9cf0b4
projectid:459512762119
current length:  38270
1 current row:  76301
2 current row:  114903
3

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand: you're running a query and then paging through the results, and the 6th page gives you a backend error?

Backend error is almost always indicative of an internal error in bigquery -- can you let me know what the project id you're using and the query job id if you have it?

Comment: In point #1 you have a query. This creates a query job and returns the query job id in the response. If you have this ID or just a project id I can look up the backend error to find out more information.

Comment: job_183c2c3919dd4d8fac9f2947201978ef
459512762119
current length:  8825
1 current row:  17650
2 current row:  26475
3 Error in runSyncQuery:'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "backendError",\n    "message": "Backend Error"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 503,\n  "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n}\n'
 None